# Android, kill/remove Asynctask at it's onPostExecute()

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm developing an app that when user clicks on a `Button` it executes an `Asynctask` that this class calls a method at it's `onPostExecute` method that calls another `Asynctask`! It works when user clicks once, but at the second time it crashes and says `Cannot execute task: the task has already been executed (a task can be executed only once)`
.

```
public class Test extends Activity {
A a;
B b;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            a = new A();
            a.execute();
        }
    });
}

class A extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // doing st
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        runB();
        a.cancel(true);
    }
}

public void runB() {
    b = new B();
    b.execute();
}

class B extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // doing st
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //doing st
        b.cancel(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: this is the actual code that causes this exception?

Comment: @njzk2: of curse not !

Comment: how do you suggest to debug a code based on another code?

Answer (score 1):

Use [AsyncTask.Status](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.Status.html) for checking status of `AsyncTask` before calling `AsyncTask.execute()` method on Button onClick:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
      if(a ==null){
        a = new A();
        a.execute();
      }
    }
```

And in `onPostExecute` of `B` class assign `null`  to  `a` :

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //doing st
        b.cancel(true);
        a=null;
    }
```

Comment: so you suggest to call `execute` on a finished asynctask?

Comment: @njzk2: yes then what is issue ?

Comment: the doc says `The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)`. Also the exception of the OP says `a task can be executed only once`.